# Why is Webpack adding brackets to this line of code?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack

I'm using Webpack to concatenate and uglify several different modules, all of which I'm importing into my main.js file.

One of the modules includes the following lines of code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    new Favorites.Factory;
});
```

But in the main.js file that Webpack generates, those lines of code become:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    new Favorites.Factory(); // Note the extra brackets
});
```

Note the brackets that were added after Factory. This creates the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Favorites.Factory is not a constructor
```

Why is Webpack adding those brackets, and how can I prevent it?

You can take a look at the full module [here](https://github.com/kylephillips/favorites/blob/master/assets/js/favorites.js) (it's a Wordpress plugin).

Comment: I fail to see in which case should a factory be invoked with the `new` keyword. Seems to me that the problem is not the parens but using new with a static factory...

Answer (score 0):

Technically I can answer your question very easy:
webpack adds brackets because of this [reason](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/new-parens)

So, not the webpack is cause of this error.

There's not much info in your post (like what happens in main.js, the way you "includes" you modules, what is your webpack config etc.), but I tried to run your code and made some assumptions: the [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor) you've got, for your particular case, means that `Favorites.Factory` is `undefined`, most probably because `favorites_data` is not defined on modules init.